# How to pass global option to future workers?

Tags: r, future

I use `future.apply` to parallelize tasks in R. In my global environment I set an option, which is specific to the package I'm using. I've observed that this option is not passed on to the workers used by `future.apply`.

How can I pass the options I've set to each worker used by `future.apply`?

Comment: what about `future.globals=TRUE` argument?

Comment: That's set to `TRUE` (by default).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the {future} package (which the {future.apply} functions rely upon) doesn't yet support the passing of global options, though [the development team is working on it.](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/134)

The [current workaround](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/134#issue-214818468) is to redeclare the options inside of your expression or function being used in `future.lapply()` or similar functions.

Here's a reproducible example of the current behavior:

```r
library(future.apply)

# Example data
datasets <- list(
  'Sample 1' = c(1, 2, NA_real_, 4),
  'Sample 2' = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
)

# Example option and function

  options(na_handling = 'remove')
  
  mean_fn <- function(x) {
    na_option <- getOption('na_handling')
    if (!is.null(na_option) && na_option == "remove") {
      mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    } else {
      mean(x, na.rm = FALSE)
    }
  }

# Use `future_lapply` like normal

  plan(multiprocess(workers = 2))
  future_lapply(X = datasets,
                FUN = mean_fn)
#> $`Sample 1`
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $`Sample 2`
#> [1] 2.5
```

And here's the workaround where you manually declare the option inside of your function/expression.

```r
# Manually pass option

  future_lapply(X = datasets,
                FUN = function(x) {
                  options(na_handling = 'remove')
                  mean_fn(x)
                })
#> $`Sample 1`
#> [1] 2.333333
#> 
#> $`Sample 2`
#> [1] 2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>